# change my apple id country

Tags: mac-appstore, ios-appstore

In my apple account there is $0.15. When ever I try to change my country it says "you have store credit balance; you must spend your balance before you can change stores."

If there is a way to change countries please share your info.

Comment: Aside from spending the money or contacting store support to have them write off that small balance?